# How to generate multiple lines of example command line when using python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python code called dd.py as follows.

```
import argparse

## Define the command line arguments

example_commands='''Example commands:\n
1. CAZyme annotation with isolated genome sequence as input \n
run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna prok \n
2. CAZyme annotation with isolated protein sequence as input \n
run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.faa protein \n
3. CAZyme annotation with meta genome as input \n
run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna meta \n
4. CAZyme and CGC annotation with meta genome as input \n
run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna meta -c EscheriaColiK12MG1655.gff \n
5. CAZyme, CGC annotation and substrate prediction with meta genome as input \n
run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna meta -c EscheriaColiK12MG1655.gff --cgc_substrate \n'''

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=example_commands)
parser.add_argument('input_file', help='Input file path')
parser.add_argument('input_type', choices=['prok', 'protein', 'meta'], help='Input type (prok, protein, or meta)')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--gff_file', help='GFF file path')
parser.add_argument('--cgc_substrate', action='store_true', help='Enable substrate prediction')

# Parse the command line arguments and display the help message
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I want to type `python dd.py --help` to generate multiple example command lines with line breaks as following

```
(base) ➜  ~ python dd.py --help
usage: dd.py [-h] [-c GFF_FILE] [--cgc_substrate] input_file {prok,protein,meta}

Example commands: 
1. CAZyme annotation with isolated genome sequence as input run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna prok 
2. CAZyme annotation with isolated protein
sequence as input 
run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.faa protein 
3. CAZyme annotation with meta genome as input 
run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna meta 
4. CAZyme and CGC annotation with meta genome as input 
run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna meta -c EscheriaColiK12MG1655.gff 
5. CAZyme, CGC annotation and substrate prediction with meta genome as input 
run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna meta -c EscheriaColiK12MG1655.gff --cgc_substrate

positional arguments:
  input_file            Input file path
  {prok,protein,meta}   Input type (prok, protein, or meta)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -c GFF_FILE, --gff_file GFF_FILE
                        GFF file path
  --cgc_substrate       Enable substrate prediction
```

However, it actually prints out in this way. What should I do?

```
(base) ➜  ~ python dd.py --help
usage: dd.py [-h] [-c GFF_FILE] [--cgc_substrate] input_file {prok,protein,meta}

Example commands: 1. CAZyme annotation with isolated genome sequence as input run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna prok 2. CAZyme annotation with isolated protein
sequence as input run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.faa protein 3. CAZyme annotation with meta genome as input run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna meta 4. CAZyme and CGC
annotation with meta genome as input run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna meta -c EscheriaColiK12MG1655.gff 5. CAZyme, CGC annotation and substrate prediction with meta
genome as input run_dbcan EscheriaColiK12MG1655.fna meta -c EscheriaColiK12MG1655.gff --cgc_substrate

positional arguments:
  input_file            Input file path
  {prok,protein,meta}   Input type (prok, protein, or meta)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -c GFF_FILE, --gff_file GFF_FILE
                        GFF file path
  --cgc_substrate       Enable substrate prediction
```

Comment: Since it's just the description that's multiline, look into 
 using `argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter`

Answer (score 2):

The default help formatter tries to wrap your text itself. Use a different one, perhaps `RawTextHelpFormatter` instead.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=example_commands,
                                 formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#formatter-class for more detailed descriptions of the available formatters to decide which is most appropriate (or look at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/argparse.py#L152) if you want to consider writing your own formatter class).

(Technically, all details about `HelpFormatter` are private to the implementation, but I'm not sure it's changed significantly in the last decade or so. Caveat emptor and all that.)